# The behavior of array within an object is not making sense

Tags: java, arrays

I am a Java beginner. I am trying to change the third element value of only "array1" within the object "ta". However, "arr1" is also getting updated even though I do not believe I changed it and I do not intend to change it. I am unable to understand why this is happening.

```java
public class testArrays {

    private int array1[] ;


    public testArrays(int[] arr) {
       this.array1 = arr;
    }
    
    public String toString(String name, int arr[]) {
           String outStr = "[";
           for (int i=0; i<= arr.length-1; i++) {
           if(i < arr.length-1) 
              outStr = outStr + arr[i] + ", ";
           else
              outStr = outStr + arr[i] + "]";   
           }
           return name + " = " + outStr;    
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        
        testArrays ta = new testArrays(arr1);
        
        System.out.println(ta.toString("arr1 Before ",arr1));   
        System.out.println(ta.toString("ta.array1 Before ", ta.array1));    
        
        ta.array1[2] = 333;
        
        System.out.println(ta.toString("arr1 After ",arr1));    
        System.out.println(ta.toString("ta.array1 After ", ta.array1)); 
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
arr1 Before  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
ta.array1 Before  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
arr1 After  = [1, 2, 333, 4, 5, 6, 7]
ta.array1 After  = [1, 2, 333, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I have used debugger to trace my steps, but after line 33 both arr1 and ta.array1 are getting updated instantaneously.

Here's the output I was expecting:

```
arr1 Before  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
ta.array1 Before  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
arr1 After  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
ta.array1 After  = [1, 2, 333, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
testArrays ta = new testArrays(arr1);
```

It creates a new object/instance of type `testArrays` and it assigns the instance variable `array1`. It now holds the same reference as `arr1` (in main). In other words, both `array1` and `arr1` point to the **same** array object in memory. Hence, you can update the array through either reference.

To avoid this, you have to create a [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,%20int)) of the array and pass it to `testArrays` class. Or you can make a copy inside the `testArrays` constructor as well

```
 testArrays ta = new testArrays(Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length));
 //or
 public testArrays(int[] arr) {
       this.array1 = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length);
 }
```

Now, we have two array objects in memory. `arr1` in main points to the initial array you've created and `array1` points to the cloned array.

---

P.S: You have to update your class name from `testArrays` to `TestArrays` to follow Java's naming convention (class names start with upper case).